# R Markdown issue i can`t really understand the error?

Tags: r, r-markdown

The R markdown could not give me the html file as i press the knit option it keep showing me this error to my following command.The code chunk does not give any error it`s runs and give the require output but the final html file wasn`t generating

```
library(BHH2)
poison.data<-poison.data
poison.data
```

The Error is-
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'poison.data' not found
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Comment: From where do you get `poison.data` ?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with RMarkdown. The error "object not found" means the object was not found, in any context. Your example isn't reproducible, but at a guess, the reason your chunk ran interactively is because you have loaded `poison.data` elsewhere and so it was found. When knitting a document knitr always uses a fresh environment, so it can't find an in-built dataset that hasn't been loaded with `data(poison.data)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `poison.data` is a built-in data set in package BHH2. You can try this:

````
---
title: "Your title"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(BHH2)
data(poison.data)
poison.data
```
````

Sample output:

[image]

The documentation of `data()` has useful information. You can access it with `?data` in your console.